# How assign different material to strokes in grease pencil mode

Tags: materials, grease-pencil

How can I assing different material to strokes? I was drawing strokes (see picture) using material named "face1" but want to change it to material "face", how can I do it? Or the only way is to to redraw entire image?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by selecting the stroke(s) you want to change in edit mode. After that, select your material "face" in the "Material" tab then click on assign just below. 
Or go to the stroke menu -> assign Material.