# How can I copy the material assigned to grease pencil2.8 strokes to other strokes?

Tags: grease-pencil

I want to copy stroke material to another stroke. 
Is that possible in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 1):

An answer can be found here: [How assign different material to strokes in grease pencil mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124387/how-assign-different-material-to-strokes-in-grease-pencil-mode/124433#124433)
You can use the assign button in the material panel after selecting the stroke

---

**To assign a material to several strokes (for example, set all blue stokes in black)**

- You can select the blue material in the materials panel, then select the black one in the drop-down menu

[image]

- Or you can switch to edit mode, select the blue lines by clicking on "select" in the materials panel and then select the black material and click on "assign" (or you can go to Stroke menu -> assign Material)

  [image]

**But it is also possible to change the material of just one blue stroke.**

Just select it manually in the viewport and then assign the new materials according to the same procedure as above ("assign" in material panel or via the Stroke Menu)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
However, I may not know the copy source material. In that case, can I only reassign material to all strokes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about the copy source material. You can of course assign the material of one stroke to several other strokes (and even to all of them). I edited the answer with some details. Let me know if it answers your question or not.

Comment: Dear MBr Thank you for your polite answer.
What I mean is to copy the star material to the red square material. I can not tell if the material of the star is Black or Black.001. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdT2D.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdT2D.jpg)

Comment: I can do this by clicking on the eye icon and flashing, but it's hard to do often. It's easy if I can select a star, copy it, then select and paste a red square.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike mesh objects, blender does not provide a way to say this stroke uses this material, but there are ways to go the other way - to say this material is used by these strokes.

In edit mode :-

- Select a material and click the Select button under the materials list.
- Click the eye icon to hide strokes using that material.
- Click the monitor icon at the bottom of the list to hide strokes that don't use the selected material.

[image: grease pencil materials panel]

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.  My friend made an addon for material serect.  I decided to use an addon. I want to know the material after selecting the stroke first.

Comment: I use more than 20 materials, so it is difficult to click each one.